# Quill example => Uncaught Error: [Parchment] Cannot insert link into block

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, quill

I try to make working an example in the [Quill documentation](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment#example).

I get the following error when trying to insert the extended link:

```
registry.ts:18 Uncaught Error: [Parchment] Cannot insert link into block
    at new e (registry.ts:18)
    at e.insertBefore (container.ts:116)
    at e.value (block.js:106)
    at e.t.wrap (shadow.ts:148)
    at e.t.formatAt (shadow.ts:70)
    at container.ts:98
    at t.forEachAt (linked-list.ts:114)
    at e.formatAt (container.ts:97)
    at e.formatAt (block.ts:42)
    at e.value (block.js:78)
```

I'm working on it since many hours without figuring out why it does not work. Any help is welcome. Here a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/5tsnyLuh/35/